# find and match strings in a string

Tags: jquery

I have a string, say:

```
<div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img3.png" class="bordered"></div>
<div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img4.png" class="bordered"></div>
<div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img10.png" class="bordered"></div>
<div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img99.png" class="bordered"></div>
```

How do I go about removing `<img>` with an SRC that matches a variable, say `$imgURL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to process a html string, i would use

```
var string = '<div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img3.png" class="bordered"></div><div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img4.png" class="bordered"></div><div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img10.png" class="bordered"></div><div class="thumb"><img src="/static/img/uploads/img99.png" class="bordered"></div>';
var imgurl = '';

var $tmp = $('<div />', {
    html: string
});
$tmp.find('div.thumb img[src="' + imgurl + '"]').parent().remove();

//not if you want the updated string then 
var newstring = $tmp.html();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L3QPK/)